# Reading csv with pyspark that has two similar kinds of line seperation

Tags: csv, pyspark, line-breaks

I am trying to read a csv using pyspark with two kinds of linebreaks. Here is an example:

```
XYZ;555;Lorem;09-01-2023\n
ABC;123;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\r\n 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore \r\n
et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.;01-02-2022\n
CDE;456;Lorem;02-05-2022\n
```

I am trying to read the file in using the following code:

```
df_read_data = spark.read.format("csv") \
            .options(header='True', lineSep='\n', delimiter=';', multiLine='True', mode='PERMISSIVE', encoding="UTF-8", ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace='True', ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace='True') \
            .load('abfss://XXX@storage-account.dfs.core.windows.net/test.csv')
```

Now obviously due to the inline breaks using `\n` as part of the line sep the final dataframe turns out wrong. The content of the rows is not located in the correct columns. Is there any way to tell spark to ignore `\r\n` as its an inline-break (not meant to be the start of a new row) and only look at isolated `\n` as line sep?
Excel somehow magically knows whats up right out the box.